# CompletableFuture tasks doesn't run in parallel

Tags: java, completable-future

I have problem where `CompletableFuture` tasks in a loop doesn't run in parallel but sychronously:

```
List<List<File>> filesLists = divideArrayIntoChunks(Arrays.asList(filesArray), 10);

        // number of tasks
        int numberOfTasks = filesLists.size();

        List<CompletableFuture<TreeMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>>> builderPartsMapFutures = Lists
                .newArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++) {

            List<File> filesList = filesLists.get(i);

            builderPartsMapFutures.add(getCompetableFutureResult(filesList, fileNameAndCharactersAmountMatchersMap,
                    namesElementsMap, namesAndFileNamesMatchingCharactersMap));
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        CompletableFuture[] futureResultArray = builderPartsMapFutures
                .toArray(new CompletableFuture[builderPartsMapFutures.size()]);

        CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(futureResultArray);

        combinedFuture.get();

        CompletableFuture<List<TreeMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>>> finalResults = combinedFuture.thenApply(
                voidd -> builderPartsMapFutures.stream().map(future -> future.join()).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        finalResults.thenAccept(result -> System.out.println(result));
```

This is `getCompetableFutureResult()` method:

```
public static CompletableFuture<TreeMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>> getCompetableFutureResult(
            List<File> filesList, HashMap<String, Integer> fileNameAndCharactersAmountMatchersMap,
            TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>> namesElementsMap,
            TreeMap<String, Map<String, Integer>> namesAndFileNamesMatchingCharactersMap) {

        return CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> buildNamesAndFileNamesWithMatchingCharactersMapForEachChunk(filesList,
                        fileNameAndCharactersAmountMatchersMap, namesElementsMap,
                        namesAndFileNamesMatchingCharactersMap));
    }
```

Comment: How do you say it runs sequentially?

Comment: @JudeNiroshan I mean buildNamesAndFileNamesWithMatchingCharactersMapForEachChunk method (from getCompetableFutureResult) runs once -> finish and then runs 2nd -> finish etc.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier)
> ```
>
> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is asynchronously completed by a
> task running in the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() with the value obtained
> by calling the given Supplier.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-

Here is a simplified version of the same workflow in your code.

```
    List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        int finalI = i;
        futures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println(finalI);
            return 3;
        }));
    }

    System.out.println("before running all of");
    CompletableFuture<Void> allOf = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[3]));
    try {
        allOf.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output shows that threads are running asynchronously. It is not one after the other.

```
before running all of
0
1
2
5
3
9
10
4
14
11
16
6
15
13
12
20
7
19
18
17
8
```

Comment: Yes, I realized that there were unavailable cores. So everything works fine.

Comment: Any reason why you're specifying the size of 3 for a list that's holds 21 elements in `new CompletableFuture[3]`?

Comment: @Scratteactually not, it doesn't matter there